# Undefined variable on PHP

Tags: php

**Hy developers i have this problem**

```
    <?php if (isset($_POST['title'])) : ?>
        <?php $idea_title = $_POST['title']; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if (isset($_POST['text'])) : ?>
        <?php $idea_text = $_POST['text']; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

```
<?php $new_idea = array('title' => $idea_title, 'text' => $idea_text);  ?>
<?php $new_idea_keys_string = implode(', ', array_keys($new_idea)); ?>
<?php $new_idea_placeholders = ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($new_idea));  ?>
```

*Warning: Undefined variable $idea_title in /in/bO5i2 on line 11
Warning: Undefined variable $idea_text in /in/bO5i2 on line 11*
**i get this error i don't know why because i thinlk that i alredy defined the variables in the first IF**

Comment: You only define the variable when the `if` condition is true. You need to give the variable a default value in other cases.

Comment: Yes brother because i want to update informations in the server, so that i want to accept informations only when the uset press Submit, i don't know if i'm right cause i'm new in PHP, and thank's again

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on PHP, so I'll ask: why does every line have a PHP opening and closing tag?

Comment: All the code that uses `$idea_title` needs to be inside the `if`.

Comment: @Robson It doesn't need it, it's just a style issue.

Comment: @Barmar That makes sense - thanks for confirming.

Comment: @Robson just styling, i can do only one tag wit all the lines, same result